# Complicated ASCII file parsing with Python

Tags: python, parsing, ascii

I am having hard times parsing an ASCII that looks like below. 
I need to create an array named as first alphabetical item in comment line (starts with '--') and append to it all numbers between that comment line  and an in-line '/'.
There might be several such records in file.

```
-- LIQ units - sm³/day  ( 8 values )
  500.0  1000.0  1500.0  2000.0  3000.0 
 4000.0  5000.0  6000.0  /

-- GRAT units - sm³/day  ( 7 values )
    0.0 200000.0 400000.0 600000.0 800000.0 
999999.9 1200000.0 /
```

for example, I expect to get `liq = [500.0, 1000.0, 1500.0, 2000.0, 3000.0, 4000.0, 5000.0, 6000.0]`

Comment: Are you sure you really want *variable names* to be dynamic ??? It is a rather uncommon requirement. Except for that, PLY (Python Lex Yacc) is a very powerful tool for parsing text files.

Comment: Though this is not absolute need, it is a strong preference. Normally the number of such headers is less than 6, but their names can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a general case where you would need to create variable (name) dynamically. instead use a dictionary to store all the arrays.

You could parse the lines one by one, and check if the line begins with '--'
once you find such a line, you need to parse the rest of the lines till you get a '\' at the end of the line.

and repeat the process again till end of file

something similar to this will work

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r'^--\s*(?P<name>\w+).*')

def get_data(file):
    '''gets the numbers till you find "/"
    '''
    arr = []
    for line in file:
        numbers = line.split()
        if numbers[-1] == '/':
            arr.extend(numbers[:-1])
            break
        else:
            arr.extend(numbers)
    return arr

for line in file:
    if line.startswith('--'):
        name = pat.match(line).groups()[0]
        arrays[name] = get_data(file)
```

this will return a dictionary of the format:

```
'GRAT': ['0.0',
  '200000.0',
  '400000.0',
  '600000.0',
  '800000.0',
  '999999.9',
  '1200000.0'],
 'LIQ': ['500.0',
  '1000.0',
  '1500.0',
  '2000.0',
  '3000.0',
  '4000.0',
  '5000.0',
  '6000.0']}
```

for the input you have given

Please take care of edge-cases and exception handling before using the code,

good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does the job in the way I need! Dictionary is indeed useful and simple to do here.

Comment: May I ask a small question: how would your 'get_data' function look like if there were no empty lines between records?

Comment: Assuming that the records are still newline-separated, it would'nt matter if there are no empty lines between records.
the program is essentially looking for chunks of the file which starts with "--" and ends with "/".